# How to make some threads do work before other threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Let's say I have 4 threads that should read from an array and 4 threads that should update something inside of an array. How should one go about making the read threads do all their work before the update threads but with calling all 8 at the same time.

```
thread t1 = thread(func,args);//READ
thread t2 = thread(func2,args);//WRITE
thread t3 = thread(func,args);//READ
thread t4 = thread(func,args);//READ
thread t5 = thread(func,args);//READ
thread t6 = thread(func2,args);//WRITE
thread t7 = thread(func2,args);//WRITE
thread t8 = thread(func2,args);//WRITE
```

and after that let's say I do join() on all of them.
To clarify, I want functions to make the priority happen but I'm not sure how to implement that.

The main problem I have is that even if I use the condition_variables they all start at the same time so at least some of the write threads would still go off.

Comment: If you want to do things conditionally, a `std::condition_variable` is a good place to start.

Comment: Why do you want to start all eight threads at the same time when you don't want the update threads to run until after the read threads?

Comment: If you are having trouble with condition variables them maybe post the code you can't get to work?

Comment: Let's say external things force me to do so.

Comment: condition_variable to wake up update threads each time a read thread finishes followed by a check (in update threads) to see if all the read threads are actually done or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you will have to use one of the many synchronization objects present in the standard library. There is [a lot to choose from](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread), but the one that suits this use case the best is `std::latch`.

This synchronization primitive works by holding an internal counter (initialized in the constructor) which can be decremented by calls to `count_down`. When the count reaches zero, threads waiting using  `wait` will be allowed to work.

Declare an `std::latch` in such a way that it is visible to all threads. Initialize it with 4, to say that 4 reader threads have to do their job before the latch opens and the writers can begin:

```cpp
std::latch global_latch{4};
```

In the reader threads, after finishing their job, but before exiting, call `count_down` to tell the latch that a thread is done working:

```cpp
void func(args_t args)
{
    // read
    global_latch.count_down();
}
```

On the other hand, in the writer threads, at the beginning of their work, wait on the latch using `wait` until all readers all done:

```cpp
void func2(args_t args)
{
    latch.wait();
    // write
}
```

Note that `std::latch` was standardized in C++20. If you use an earlier version of C++, you might have to use `std::experimental::latch` instead or `boost::thread::latch` from the popular [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) library. Fortunately, the interface is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Have your main thread call `join()` on all of read-threads, before it creates any of the update-threads.  `join()` will not return until the thread has exited.

Comment: That is exactly what I noted I don't want to do. I want to make them have priority done inside the functions.

Comment: @AleksaBajat I don't see such note in the question.